# Android Studio Throws exception during project sync

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I uploaded my code from my desktop computer to github,  and when i pulled the code to my laptop (for the first time) i ran into this issue when i tried syncing my project with gradle files. I posted the error message printed below.

I am also unable to rebuild or clean the project. The java compiler also has trouble resolving the character "R", but i assume this is because i am unable to sync the project.

I appreciate the help!

```
 Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process  not ready to receive commands

Thread(png-cruncher_25): Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:144)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your aapt binary for your Build Tools version is working:

```
neonigma@hyperion ~/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.3 $ ./aapt 
./aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If not as in my case, just install the missing lib:

```
neonigma@hyperion ~/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.3 $ sudo apt-get install zlib1g:i386
```

Restart your Android Studio and try again.

EDIT:

If you don't have Linux or your problem is not related with the previous comment, try to change the Build tools version in the gradle file:

buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

Comment: Thank you for the comment, i tried executing the aapt file and got the following error - bash: ./aapt: cannot execute binary file:Exec format error. The assumption i have come to is the fact that I am unable to run aapt because I dont have enough RAM. I realized I only have 2gb of RAM and the required amount, for android studio, is 3GB.

Comment: Glad to help then